# Asserting that when (P→Q) and (Q→R) are true, then so is (P→R)

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

I am going through Velleman's "how to prove it", and am stuck on Problem 16 in section 3.2, which requires me to show, with the help of truth tables, that if $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ are true, then $P\rightarrow R$ is true.

I did the truth table; it shows that when $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ are true, then so is $P\rightarrow R$. But there are also instances where $P\rightarrow R$ is true and $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ are false.
Is this indeed correct or did I do something wrong with the truth table?

Comment: See [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism#Formal_notation)

Comment: You did nothing wrong. It is indeed correct -- what makes you think it can't be?

Comment: The "follows from" relation is tested with truth table showing that in ALL cases where the premises are True, also the conclusion is (see Logical consequence).

Comment: If $P\to\lnot Q$ and $\lnot Q\to R$ are true then $P\to R$ is also true, so if you have $P\to R$ you cannot infer either premise.
.

Comment: @TonyK I thought that the columns have to be identitical. But now I understand that that has a different meaning. If the columns are identitical it means that that they are equivalent (biconditional) right?

Comment: This is sometimes called vacuous truth. "False implies anything" is true.

Comment: If $P$ and $Q$ are true then $P\land Q$ is true, right? But there are also instances where $P$ is true and $Q$ and $P\land Q$ are false. Is this correct or did I do something wrong with the truth table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The exercise requires me to show, with the help of truth tables, that if $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ are true, then $P\rightarrow R$ is true

Since we are reasoning completely abstractly, the exercise is essentially asking you to show that $$\Big((P\rightarrow Q)\land(Q\rightarrow R)\Big)\boldsymbol\to (P\rightarrow R)\tag1$$ is a tautology. Our [previous discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4681584/21813) has established that this corresponds to its truth table having entirely `T` under its main connective.

\begin{array}{ccc|c@{}c@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}ccc@{}ccc@{}c@{}c}
P&Q&R&(&P&\rightarrow&Q&)&\land&(&Q&\rightarrow&R&)&\rightarrow&(&P&\rightarrow&R&)\\\hline
1&1&1&&1&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&\\
1&1&0&&1&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&\\
1&0&1&&1&0&0&&0&&0&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&1&1&1&\\
1&0&0&&1&0&0&&0&&0&1&0&&\mathbf{1}&&1&0&0&\\
0&1&1&&0&1&1&&1&&1&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&\\
0&1&0&&0&1&1&&0&&1&0&0&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&\\
0&0&1&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&1&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&1&\\
0&0&0&&0&1&0&&1&&0&1&0&&\mathbf{1}&&0&1&0&
\end{array}

> But there are also instances where $P\rightarrow R$ is true, and $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ are false.

Sure: in these rows, sentence $(1)$ is indeed `T`.

> If A is false and B true, then can "if A, then B" be true?

Yes: in this row (in fact, in every row where hypothesis A is false), we say that the implication "if A, then B" is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#Scope_of_the_concept).

In the same row (A is false and B true), the bi-implication "A is equivalent to B", on the other hand, is certainly false.

Answer (score 6):

You ask:

> But there are also instances where $P\rightarrow R$ is true and $P\rightarrow Q$ and $Q\rightarrow R$ is false. Is this indeed correct or did I do something wrong with the truth table?

I think what you are thinking here is:  'Wait! If you can't go from $P$ to $Q$, and from $Q$ to $R$, then how can you go from $P$ to $R$?!'

Well, maybe you can get from $P$ to $S$, and from $S$ to $R$

Answer (score 3):

Consider $(P \implies Q) \equiv (\neg P \vee Q)$. And $(Q \implies R) \equiv (\neg Q \vee R)$. Then combine the two assumptions, we get $(\neg P \vee Q) \land (\neg Q \vee R)$.

Case 1. If $\neg P$, we are done since the antecedent is false.

Case 2. If $(P \land Q)$, then $R$. This implies $(\neg P \vee R)$ which is $\equiv (P \implies R)$ as desired.

The above two cases exhausted all possibilities, hence we are done.

Answer (score 2):

$S1: p\implies q \equiv q \lor !p$

$S2: q\implies r \equiv r \lor !q$

If $q$ is true then so is $S1$. We can only have $S2$ be true if $r$ is true. If $q$ is false, then S2 is true. We can only have $S1$ if $!p$. So $S1\land S2$ requires either $!p$ or $r$.

$S1 \land S2 \implies !p \lor r \equiv p \implies r$

Answer (score 2):

> I did the truth table; it shows that when $P→Q$ and $Q→R$ are true, then so is $P→R$. But there are also instances where $P→R$ is true and $P→Q$ and $Q→R$ are false. Is this indeed correct or did I do something wrong with the truth table?

It is correct.

Semantic entailment occurs exactly when: *all* interpretations of the variables that value the *premises* as true *must* also value the *conclusion* as true.

You *do not* need to consider what happens to the conclusion when one or more of the premises are false.

Answer (score 0):

Fix a natural number n.

Take P := 4 | n

Q := n is odd

R := 2 | n

P $\to$ R is true. Neither P $\to$ Q nor Q $\to$ R are true.

Comment: that's a counterexample right?